# Ui Picker view error cant resolve

Tags: ios5, uipickerview

Still trying to figure out the UI picker view, 2 days on it now and for some reason im just stuck on this.  Any advice please on what im doing wrong.  Ive got a yellow triangle saying "Incomplete implementation" and a red triangle saying "Use of undeclared identifier numberOfComponentsinPickerView"

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface pick3 : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate> {  


UIPickerView *select;    
NSArray *list;


}



@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *select;




@end
```

.m

```
#import "pick3.h"

@interface pick3 ()

@end

@implementation pick3
@synthesize select;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.




{

     list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Employed", @"Student", @"Retired",     @"Homemaker", @"Self-employed", @"Unemployed", @"Other", nil];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    //One column
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //set number of rows
    return list.count;
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //set item per row
    return [list objectAtIndex:row];
}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typo on your `viewDidLoad:` method.

You have an extra '{' before your 'list' and and extra '}' at the end of the file. Just remove them and you'll be ok.

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

     list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Employed", @"Student", @"Retired",     @"Homemaker", @"Self-employed", @"Unemployed", @"Other", nil];
}
```

Comment: Ahhh! the curly brackets had put a halt on proceedings, thank you again for your help, its very! much appreciated from a new programmer.